# Fetch --no-history chromium getting stuck

Tags: browser, chromium

I am trying to develop my own browser for fun and I am following [this turorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p34rr443eE0). The problem arises when I get to the part where I should fetch chromium by using the command `fetch --no-history chromium`. When it is done with some part it starts to hung up on "Still working on: src" and keeps repeating it forever:

```
1>Cloning into 'C:\chromium\_gclient_src_p6la7lya'...
1>remote: Finding sources: 100% (410801/410801)
1>remote: Total 410801 (delta 94529), reused 259376 (delta 94529)
1>Receiving objects: 100% (410801/410801), 1.18 GiB | 9.26 MiB/s, done.
1>Resolving deltas: 100% (94529/94529), done.

[0:03:40] Still working on:
[0:03:40]   src

[0:03:50] Still working on:
[0:03:50]   src

[0:04:00] Still working on:
[0:04:00]   src

[0:04:10] Still working on:
[0:04:10]   src
```

I have tried to stop it, remove all files, restarted computer etc. Nothing works and it is still stuck like this. Has anyone else experienced this issue and knows what is going on?

Comment: Did you get it working? Ran into same problem. Some random comment somewhere said it took 10 hours.

Comment: @petke, nope it kept going like that over night (12+ hours) and then I gave up.

Comment: I left it overnight. Was finished (and ok) by morning. Not sure how long it took. Looks like it might have taken just 2 hours. I'm not sure but i think its slow because google throttles chromium git downloads. So if spamming them too often, it might take even longer.